# What is the default setting in Chrome debugger regarding source maps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

When you just download Google Chrome for the first time, what is the default setting on source maps?

There is a checkbox in the general settings panel of the Chrome debugger that says 'Enable JS source maps' - Is this checked or unchecked by default when you install Chrome for the first time? Mine is ticked, but I can't remember whether it was like that from the beginning or if I ticked it manually - Resetting Chrome settings to factory defaults doesn't seem to reset the debugger settings so there is no way to tell.

It's for a tutorial I'm writing.

Comment: Run Chrome in a new profile using `chromium --user-data-dir=/tmp/whatever` and you'll know

Answer (score 1):

Following Rob W's advice, it appears that source mapping is enabled by default.